# Writing XML from a hashtable converted to a table object then loaded to a dataset

Tags: c#, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <blog>
    <Title xsi:type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Testing this XML File</Title>
    <Name xsi:type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Shawn</Name>
    <Image xsi:type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Hosting\html\blogimage\</image>
    <Comment xsi:type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Shawn is testing this file</Comment>
  </blog>
</NewDataSet>
```

When I am using a Dataset Writexml Method I keep getting this xml file type, I want my XML file to look like this:

```
<NewDataSet>
  <blog>
    <Title>Testing this XML File</Title>
    <Name>Shawn</Name>
    <Image>Hosting\html\blogimage\</image>
    <Comment>Shawn is testing this file</Comment>
  </blog>
</NewDataSet>
```

This xml is for a blog with a path to the image file so when the blog loades it will load the image
I want to know will the first xml in the naming tags be effected when I want to call the xml tags for reading the xml file with the w3c links in the tags need to understand why they are writing like this from a dataset it never done that before.

This is the code before the xml is written: Sample

```
public void WriteDataXml(string name, string title, string comment, string path)
    {

      DataSet ds = new DataSet();

     //Sets the data in the hashtable to write new file
     Hashtable lines = new Hashtable();
     lines["Name"] = name;
     lines["Title"] = title;
     lines["Comment"] = comment;
     lines["image"] = path;

     //Convert hash table to data table
     //create an instance of DataTable
     var dataTable = new DataTable(lines.GetType().Name);
     //specify the table name       
     dataTable.TableName = "blog";
     //fill the columns in the DataTable
     foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in lines)
     {
         dataTable.Columns.Add(entry.Key.ToString(), typeof(object));
     }

     //create a new DataRow in the DataTable    
     DataRow dr = dataTable.NewRow();
     //fill the new row in the DataTable
     foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in lines)
     {
         dr[entry.Key.ToString()] = entry.Value.ToString();
     }
     //add the filled up row to the DataTable
     dataTable.Rows.Add(dr);

    //Appending To Existing: Pass values to the dataset to write the xml file from the hash table

     // Add Table to dataset ds
     ds.Tables.Add(dataTable);

    //Reading Existing: Also include current files from the xml in the data set by reading and current

    //Write XML
     string filename = Server.MapPath(@".\blog\") + "comments.xml";
     ds.WriteXml(filename);

    }
```

Comment: If you've started with the data *not* in a DataTable (I'd prefer Dictionary over HashTable) why did you put it in a DataTable? Do you *need* to?

Comment: Well you use datatables to add data to a dataset then with the dataset you write the xml file, I used the hash table to receive the data for the data-table cause its easy to convert the hash-table to a table less writing. The has-table is a Data-table populator of a sort.

Comment: I added my xmlwriter method up above so you can see the initialization of the xml file, There is something that is including the W3C Links is that cause the definition of the table is an object cause of the image path or can I define the table as string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of all your code you can create xml with Linq to Xml:

```
public static void WriteDataXml(
    string name, string title, string comment, string path)
{
    XDocument xdoc = new XDocument(
        new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
        new XElement("Blog",
            new XElement("Title", title),
            new XElement("Name", name),
            new XElement("Image", path),
            new XElement("Comment", comment)));

    string filename = Server.MapPath(@".\blog\") + "comments.xml";
    xdoc.Save(filename);
}
```

Output (I think `NewDataSet` element is not necessary here):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Blog>
  <Title>Testing this XML File</Title>
  <Name>Bob</Name>
  <Image>Hosting\html\blogimage\</Image>
  <Comment>Shawn is testing this file</Comment>
</Blog>
```

Comment: Yeah, that is shorter for sure; I know now I can write an existing xml with linq which is nice. I also want to read a current xml and merge the existing data with an already written xml for a blog loader if possible

Comment: @shawn actually storing all comments in xml files is not very good idea. Consider to use some database instead. Also I think you should store more data - e.g. timestamp for comment. And, if you really want to use xml, then consider to use different structure of xml file. e.g. Blog > Comments > Comment. And create some entities which will hold data. E.g. Blog and Comment entities

Comment: Well You can use XML Data for blogs in one way and the easy way is to use the Dateset Merge method before writing the xml it helps adjust and update Dataset Scheme for xml propergating